# What are the olfactory chemicals in whiteboard/permanent markers and what do they bind to in the nose, lungs, and brain?

Tags: biochemistry, organic-chemistry

What are the olfactory chemicals in whiteboard/permanent markers and what do they bind to in the nose, lungs, and brain?

Comment: Anyway... [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cbdv.200890101) is one relevant paper on human olfactory receptors.

Comment: here's another paper that might shed light on the second part of your question... http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002224

Comment: personally i find ethanol and its closest homologs smell 'sweet'

Comment: That make some sense just looking at the mocules. They both bind to the olfactories in a similar way. using the H-OH side.

Answer (score 6):

The smell of dry erase markers come from the chemicals ethanol, butanol and isopropyl alcohol. Like all chemicals inhaled through the nose, they bind to the Receptor neurons in the located in the back of the nose. The neurons interpret the chemicals using a 'lock-and-key' model but the specific way its coded and perceived in humans is still being researched and the process is not completely understood.